# How do I find the difference between one event timestamp and the first event timestamp following it that is not the same event as the original?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find the difference between two timestamps that meet certain criterion. My table has ID's, timestamps, a payment state, and subtype. For a certain ID, if they've ever entered the payment state "unpaid" and the subtype "grace_period", I need to find out if that same ID has ever gone back to paying payment state "paid" and subtype "active". If so, the end result needs to be the difference between the date they became unpaid and the first date where they're active. I've included a photo for reference.

[image: Need difference between those two dates]

I've tried using IF/THEN statements and nested case statements, but none of them are really working. Assume that the dates are true datetimes.

Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

use datediff and case when

```
  select id,    
  datediff(day, max(case when paymentstate='paid' and subtype='active' then date end),
        max(case when paymentstate='unpaid' and subtype='grace_period' then date end)
        ) as ddiff from table group by id
```

Comment: what if a user can go between states more often than once? Sorry, I forgot to add that in the original question. This would only return the furthest date, correct?

Comment: also, this wouldn't work because the first half of the argument gets the maximum date that qualifies with those criterion, correct? I need the first state change - if you look at the image I posted, this code would get the difference between the topmost date and the unpaid one, not the first date where it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift supports the `ignore null`s option so getting the dates is pretty simply:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, date, next_pa_date) as diff_in_days
from (select t.*,
             lead(case when paymentstate = 'paid' and subtype = 'active' then date end ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by date) as next_pa_date
      from t
     ) t
where paymentstate = 'unpaid' and subtype = 'grace_period' and
      next_pa_date is not null;
```